A question about private key
The private key of Bitcoin is a 256 bit binary number or a 64 bit hexadecimal number. Why isn't my 64 bit Bitcoin private key in hexadecimal? It starts with 'G'. How can I obtain the correct private key through this string starting with 'G'? Thanks
To my knowledge, the format of a Bitcoin private key should be a binary number of 256 characters, a hexadecimal number of 64 characters, a string of over 50 characters encoded by BASE, or a string starting with "5" encoded by WIF. However, my private key is a string of 64 characters starting with "G", including uppercase letters and numbers. I don't know what encoding or encryption it is, so I am unable to use it now. If you can help me retrieve Bitcoin, I am willing to give you a portion of Bitcoin
Additionally, I can confirm the authenticity of this private key because it was obtained from an early image that was a screenshot of a software or website and had the words' private key 'on it.

This question is similar to: What are the formats of a private key?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See also Private key to WIF process
